# Is the wrapped Fukaya category a symplectomorphism invariant?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, symplectic-topology

Say, let $\phi\colon W_1\to W_2$ be a symplectomorphism of Weinstein manifolds(or with stronger assumption that $W_1$ is Liouville homotopic equivalent to $W_2$, but with non-compact support), do they have quasi-isomorphic wrapped Fukaya categories?

Seidel's construction for symplectic cohomology in his *biased view* paper showed that symplectic cohomology is a symplectomorphism invariant, but in open string we need a Viterbo restriction functor(which is defined in [GPS2]) and a construction of homotopy limit of $A_{\infty}$-categories, which I don't know whether there're references for this.